# Turn data in file txt to DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a problem here. I have a data.txt file like this

[image: data in file txt]

I want to convert it into a dataframe like this

[image: Dataframe i want].

How can I do it. I tried the regex but it doesn't work.
Here if file
 [file](https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=xyraw.txt)

Comment: Can you attach a sample here for us to copy? It would make helping easier.

Comment: please use ``` before and after your data to avoid formatting issues. And edit your question with it. Thanks

Comment: thank you, i just add file data

Comment: I cannot access the file.

Comment: here is link https://www.dropbox.com/s/vfwumvkf4bxcqt7/xyraw.txt?dl=0 
(first time i use stack overflow so i got a little confused)

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]. Don't link to external sites, links can break and that makes the question useless for others with similar problems. We really appreciate a [mcve] here, in the question, as formatted text (use the `{}` button).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that does the trick. Note, that I read from string instead of from file, but you can easily exchange that.

```
data_string = """
15_9CANAL
15_9
         0
     0.000     1.190 <1>
     5.000     1.100
    10.000     1.160
    15.000     1.190
    16.000     1.100
    17.000     1.140
    25.000    -0.850
    30.000    -1.650
    35.000    -1.850 <2>
    40.000    -1.550
    45.000    -0.850
    48.000     1.140
    50.000     1.230
    52.000     1.230 <3>
15_9CANAL
15_9
      1500
NoData
15_9CANAL
15_9
      3000
     0.000     1.370 <1>
     5.000     1.420
    10.000     1.310
    15.000     1.390
    16.000     0.360
    17.000    -0.440
    25.000    -0.940
    30.000    -1.440
    35.000    -1.640 <2>
    40.000    -1.040
    45.000    -0.740
    48.000     0.360
    50.000     1.270
    52.000     1.430
    53.000     1.430 <3>
"""

from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
data = []
data_row = None
skip_row = False
chainage = False
for row in StringIO(data_string):
    if row.strip() == '':
        continue
    if skip_row:
        skip_row = False
        chainage = True
        continue
    elif chainage:
        chainage = False
        data_row['Chainage'] = row.strip()
    elif 'CANAL' in row:
        if data_row is not None and data_row != {}:
            data.append(data_row)
        data_row = {}
        data_row['River'] = row.strip()
        skip_row = True
    else:
        # read data
        print('row', row)
        values = [val for val in row.split(' ') if val != '']
        if values[0].strip() != 'NoData':
            data_row['x'] = values[0].strip()
            data_row['y'] = values[1].strip()
            data.append(data_row)
            data_row = {}

if data_row is not None and data_row != {}:
    data.append(data_row)
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

This results in the dataframe you are asking for.

if you want to have the canal information in all rows, just comment out the

```
if data_row is not None:
    data.append(data_row)
```

Comment: Thanks for you code, it work very well with sample file. But i have a problem, in my original file, i got a huge data. So i got a some problem.
here is file : https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ryzrp4oxnot2gf/original.txt?dl=0

Comment: It work with 15_9CANAL, but other dont work. And part data_row['y'] = values[1].strip() not work with other river

Comment: You would need to provide some further test data, if you require further help.

Comment: That all i got, i'll remember that

Comment: Let me know if there is anything else I can help with. If not, I would be thankful, if you could accept my answer.